# Full nested or flat URL in this case? Should I divide full hierarchy path into subpaths?

Tags: java, spring, url

To start, I want to say that I am not a professional programmer and I really do not know how to solve this problem correctly.

I have hierarchy: organization (one) ->(many) branch (one) -> (many) building (one)-> (many) cabinet (one) -> (many) chairs or `system_units` or desks or etc. How should I create my API URLs?

Like that:

```
/api/orgs/{orgId}/branches/{branchId}/buildings/{buildingId}/cabinets/{cabinetId}/chair/{chairId}
```

I think it is too long and hard to maintain in code (I am using Java and Spring). For building, for example, I need just branchId. For cabinet, I need only `buildingId`. I am not creating a web site, this API is needed for an Android application. For example, I have a UI form which asks to choose *Organization*, after that from a database, I get all corresponding with organization branches. Then, user chooses *Branch*, after that, user has a list of buildings corresponding with that branch, and the same with cabinet. How should I write my API in that case?

Maybe I should do @RequestMapping more flat, like that:

```
/api/orgs/{orgId}/branches               //BranchController
/api/branches/{branchId}/buildings       //BuildingController
/api/buildings/{buildingId}/cabinets     //CabinetController
/api/cabinets/{cabinetId}/chairs         //ChairController
/api/cabinets/{cabinetId}/system_units   //SystemUnitsController
/api/cabinets/{cabinetId}/desks          //DeskController
```

I need to take orgId after that `branchId` after that `buildingId` after that `cabinetId`. Or what should I do?  Which approach is better or both of them are incorrect and need to use another one?

For first approach to get list of chairs, I need methods like:

```java
//In OrganizationController
@RequestMapping("/api/orgs")
...
@GetMapping("/{orgId}/branches/{branchId}/buildings/{buildingId}/cabinets/{cabinetId}/chairs")
public List<Chair> getAllChairs(@PathVariable Long orgId, @PathVariable Long branchId, @PathVariable Long buildingId, @PathVariable Long cabinetId){
    return chairService.getChairsByCabinetId(cabinetId);
}
```

But here I need just `cabinetId` instead of all of these ids. `orgId`, `branchId`, `buildingId` will be unused.

For second approach methods will be like:

```java
//In ChairController
@RequestMapping("/api/cabinets/{cabinetId}/chairs")
...
@GetMapping
public List<Chair> getAllChairs(@PathVariable Long cabinetId){
    return chairService.getChairsByCabinetId(cabinetId);
}
```

Is second approach better? I did not check it yet, but I see that the second approach not fully semantical evident, but it is more convenient to use this API, is it not?

Please, tell me how solve this trouble.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, preference, and pragmatic considerations, and as such is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so there is no right answer? Both approaches are good from technically and programmatically point of view ?